# Highchart bar chart with categories not taking full container width

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

Highchart bar chart is not taking its parent container full width when categories are added. If I comment the categories or remove them, the chart will take the full width.

Please use this link https://jsfiddle.net/nu8dyw13/2/ to check the problem.
`Highcharts.chart('container', { legend: { enabled: false, }, boost: { useGPUTranslations: true, }, tooltip: { enabled: false, }, chart: { type: "bar", height: 50, marginTop: 5, animation: true, shadow: false, }, title: {}, credits: { enabled: false, }, xAxis: { categories: [""], title: {}, lineWidth: 0, top: 20, height: 10, }, yAxis: { offset: 0, labels: { y: 15, align: "center", }, gridLineWidth: 0.5, gridLineDashStyle: "Dash", gridZIndex: 10, top: 20, height: 10, categories: ["LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH", "GDM"], plotBands: [ { from: 0, to: 1, color: "#E3E3E3", borderColor: "#6B6B6B", borderWidth: 1, }, { from: 1, to: 2, color: "#F9FAFC", borderColor: "#6B6B6B", borderWidth: 1, }, { from: 2, to: 3, color: "#E3E3E3", borderColor: "#6B6B6B", borderWidth: 1, }, ], min: 0, max: 3, title: { text: null, }, }, series: [ { type: "bar", data: [ { y: 2, color: "#B3C618", }, ], }, ], });`

I tried overriding CSS and adding width properties but it's not working. Can someone please help?

Comment: What do you mean that bar is not taking full width? You set your point's value to 2, which equals the HIGH category. That's the length of the point. Please be more specific on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Try to comment the categories part. When commented the bar chart expands to take the full width of container. If you uncomment the categories part, the bar chart will get a bit smaller. Let me know if you need any more clarification and thank you for your support.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Unfortunately it looks like a bug, you can report it on Highcharts GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose  I provided a work around in the answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I suggest removing categories (they're causing the problem) and using labels.formatter function that will return the proper category per tick.

```
  formatter: function() {
    const categories = ["LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH", "GDM"];

    return categories[this.pos]
  }
```

API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x7L0ofkr/